# How do I setup my authentication data with rspec and factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a simple user factory that looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "jeff"
    email "jeff@lint.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

And I am trying to test the built in `authenticate` method like so:

```
  describe "return value of authenticate method", focus: true do

    before do
      create(:user)
    end

    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(:email) }

    it "can return value of authenticate method" do
      expect(:user).to eq found_user.authenticate(:password)
    end

  end
```

The error I am getting is

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

That probably means `found_user` is returning nil. But I don't understand why. When I try this code on the console, it works just fine. So what am I doing wrong? I am quite new to Factory Girl.

What I am also looking for is to get this right without using instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
describe "return value of authenticate method", focus: true do

   before do
     @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   end

   let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

   it "can return value of authenticate method" do  
     expect(@user).to eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password)
   end
end
```

Comment: This works but I want to know why using just (:user) doesn't work.

Comment: Because you assigned the values of the :user factory to @user. It's like a class. You have to instantiate it first.

Comment: So what exactly is returned by the user factory? Isn't it the same kind of object such as @user?

Comment: Isn't there a way to do all this without instance variables?

Comment: FactoryGirl infers the class of the object from your definition. In your case, it guessed that it's a User class.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I took a look at this but this did not show me a way to setup a better factory which is what I suspect is needed

Comment: The reason you assign factories to instance variables is so that you can DRY up your code. For example, you can use @user on multiple "it" blocks within your "describe" declaring it only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
  describe "return value of authenticate method", focus: true do

    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    it "can return value of authenticate method" do
      expect(:user).to eq found_user.authenticate(:password)
    end

  end
```

Someone can suggest a better RSpec way of doing this, but it will get your test to work.

Comment: When I try this, I get `Failure/Error: expect(:user).to eq found_user.authenticate(:password)
       
       expected: false
            got: :user`

Comment: This line is wrong `expect(:user).to eq found_user.authenticate(:password)`. You need to pass meaningful values to `expect` and to `authenticate`, not just symbols.